# how to do dynamic pagination in android recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have PAGE_SIZE=10 and PAGE_NUM=1,per page it has to display 10 records while scrolling the page again it has to append with the next 10 records and has to update the PAGE_SIZE as well as every end of the 10th record it has to show the ProgressBar also dynamically.

Referred this link.
http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/

I was trying to update the adapter but I am getting only the first 10 records,not the next upcoming records.

It would be very helpful if anyone guide me to address this issue.

**Activity.java**

```
     recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager) {
                    @Override
                    protected void loadMoreItems() {
                        isLoading=true;
                        PAGE_NUM = PAGE_NUM + 1;
                        getData();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getTotalPageCount() {
                        return PAGE_NUM;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isLastPage() {
                        return isLastPage;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isLoading() {
                        return isLoading;
                    }
                });

 public void getData(){
     client.sendAsync(restRequest, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, final RestResponse result) {
                        try {
                            responseJsonObject = result.asJSONObject();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {
                                                jsonArrayList = DataHelper.populateJSONObjectList(responseJsonObject);
                                                result= DataHelper.getList(jsonArrayList);
                                                Log.d("result list>>", result.size() + "");
                                                dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, result, client, jsonArrayList);
                                                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                                               if(!isLoading){
                                                    /*if(result.size()==PAGE_SIZE)
                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    if((result.size()%PAGE_SIZE)!=1){
                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);}*/
                                                       dataAdapter.addData(result);

                                                }

                                                if (result.size() > PAGE_SIZE) {
                                                    isLoading = false;
                                                    dataAdapter .addLoadingFooter();
                                                } else {
                                                    isLastPage = true;
                                                }

        }
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public void addData(List<Item> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            this.list.add(list.get(i));
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 public void addLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = true;
        add(new Item());
    }

public void removeLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = false;

        int position = list.size() - 1;
        Item item = getItem(position);

        if (item != null) {
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is when you do pagination only first time you have to set the adapter

```
dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, result, client, jsonArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and then on every 
 `loadMore function`

you have to add extra 10 items in the your `jsonArrayList` instead of setting new adapter each time.

If you set the adapter each time you will not have your previous items.

Hope you understand that on `loadMore` you have to call function which add 10 new items to your `jsonArrayList` using `jsonArrayList.add(result)` then you have to call  `notifyDataChanged` on adapter object.

//use this 
in onCreate method

```
dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, result, client, jsonArrayList);                       
recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);





recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager) {
                    @Override
                    protected void loadMoreItems() {
                        isLoading=true;
                        PAGE_NUM = PAGE_NUM + 1;
                        getData();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getTotalPageCount() {
                        return PAGE_NUM;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isLastPage() {
                        return isLastPage;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isLoading() {
                        return isLoading;
                    }
                });

 public void getData(){
     client.sendAsync(restRequest, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, final RestResponse result) {
                        try {
                            responseJsonObject = result.asJSONObject();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {
                                                jsonArrayList = DataHelper.populateJSONObjectList(responseJsonObject);
                                                result= DataHelper.getList(jsonArrayList);
                                                Log.d("result list>>", result.size() + "");

                                               if(!isLoading){
                                                    /*if(result.size()==PAGE_SIZE)
                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    if((result.size()%PAGE_SIZE)!=1){
                                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);}*/
                                                       dataAdapter.addData(result);

                                                }

                                                if (result.size() > PAGE_SIZE) {
                                                    isLoading = false;
                                                    dataAdapter .addLoadingFooter();
                                                } else {
                                                    isLastPage = true;
                                                }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify your code.

declarations :

```
int PAGE_SIZE=10; //Number of items per page
int PAge_NUM=1; // page num with websevices providing accordingly
boolean mIsLoading=false; // fetching more data
boolean isMoreDataAvailable=true; // more data still available
```

Recycler's Scroll Listener

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (mIsLoading)
                    return;
                int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                    //Scrolled to End of list
                    if (dataAdapter != null && dataAdapter.getItemCount() < mTotalNoOfData && isMoreDataAvailable) {

                        getData();


      }
            }
        }
    });
```

Fetch data method; may be WS call

```
public void getData(){
     client.sendAsync(restRequest, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, final RestResponse result) {
                        try {
                            responseJsonObject = result.asJSONObject();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {
                                                jsonArrayList = DataHelper.populateJSONObjectList(responseJsonObject);
                                                result= DataHelper.getList(jsonArrayList);
                                                Log.d("result list>>", result.size() + "");
                        if(dataAdapter!=null && result.size()>0){
                        dataAdapter.addMoreDataToList(result); // just append more data to current list
                        }else{
                                                dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, result, client, jsonArrayList);
                                                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);// setAdapter for first time only
                        }

                        if(result!=null){
                            if( result.size()<PAGE_SIZE)}
                            isMoreDataAvailable=false;
                            }
                        }


        }
```

Add this method to your adapter

```
public void addMoreDataToList(ArrayList result){
currentDataList.addAll(result);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I modification I might have removed some of your code.
Hope this helps you..!!

Comment: may I know how to get mTotalDialogsWithCurrentUser? @Dhaval

Comment: edited, its a int value suggesting total no of items available

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add second type for loading footer to Adapter and add items via notifyItemAdded()?